# Downgrading RoR from 5.0.0 to 4.2.1: undefined method `to_time_preserves_timezone=' for ActiveSupport:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently trying to downgrade my RoR application from 5.0.0 to 4.2.1 since certain gems like activeadmin do not seem to work with 5.0.0 so well.

However, I get this error which unfortunately does not really tell me much when doing **rake db:migrate**

```
undefined method `to_time_preserves_timezone=' for ActiveSupport:Module
```

This is what my Gemfile looks like:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Postgress
gem 'pg'
# Authentication
gem 'devise'

# Use activeadmin for administration
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Slim support
gem "slim-rails"
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported      runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:    https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:    https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Bootstrap forms
gem 'bootstrap_form'

# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a     debugger console
gem 'byebug'

# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring'

end
```

Thank you very much in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all...yikes. Downgrading is never fun.

`gem list` and see which version of `activesupport` is listed. Rails 4.2.1 is going to need the previous version `activesupport 4.2.1` along with a bunch of other gems.

You'll probably want to delete the `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install` after that, as the correct version will then be fetched. I guarantee this will be messy, but the core rails gems should downgrade at the very least.

Edit: I'm also going to guess that there will be Rails 5.0 dependencies in your project which will then break in the rollback process, so this may not even completely solve your issue. It's worth a try though.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting Gemfile.lock and running 'bundle install' will install the recent versions of gems written in gemfile unless version is specified. That may cause compatibility issues with version 4.2.1.

This might be an issue occurred due to the up-gradation of Rails 5.0. Please ensure the project directory doesn't contain configuration files which support Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by commenting out the config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb. That file is part of Rails 5. Everything seemed to work afterward.